# Prevent Angular Ancestor Dependency Injection

Tags: angular

Suppose I have the following component `ChildComponent`. It can *optionally* be used inside a `ParentComponent`, and its behavior changes based upon whether or not it is used inside a `ParentComponent`, and so it takes `ParentComponent` as a dependency injection in its constructor. Hopefully nothing controversial thus far:

```
class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Optional() parentComponent: ParentComponent) {
    // Do stuff based upon whether or not `parentComponent` is defined...
  }
}
```

Now suppose `ChildComponent` can also be used inside a component `FooComponent`, with the following caveat. I want `FooComponent` to **prevent** any ancestor injections of `ParentComponent`. Two examples to demonstrate what I mean:

**Example #1:**

In this case, `ParentComponent` should be properly injected into `ChildComponent`.

```
<foo-component>
  <parent-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
  </parent-component>
</foo-component>
```

**Example #2:**

In this case, `ParentComponent` should not be injected into `ChildComponent`, because it is **blocked** by `FooComponent`.

```
<parent-component>
  <foo-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
  </foo-component>
</parent-component>
```

What is the appropriate way of accomplishing this? I looked into the various decorators here (https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#hierarchical-injectors) and found the documentation confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time looking into this and found one solution (not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this):

`FooComponent` can provide `ParentComponent` as `undefined` in its providers. Consequently, `ChildComponent` will receive `undefined` in its dependency injection. Something like the following:

```
@Component({
  providers: [{provide: ParentComponent, useValue: undefined}],
})
class FooComponent {

}
```